# Mariadb - information schema queries really slow

Tags: mariadb

Ever since upgrading to Fedora 23, information schema queries have become very slow. This is an installation that started as mysql in Fedora 17. The change definitely happened with the upgrade to 23.

```
mysql
use information_schema
select * from tables
....
+---------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 5237 rows in set, 11 warnings (1 min 7.32 sec)

 MariaDB [information_schema]>
```

There are 28 databases, none particularly large.

Is there any sort of clean up or optimization that can be done to make this reasonable again?

Thanks

Comment: You are asking a BAD question !!  Provider more information.  Imagine somebody ask you, why my car run slowly recently?

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB was/is on the machines?  (There have been changes in this area.)

Comment: `SHOW WARNINGS;` -- there may be a clue there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a regression...

That query has to "open" every table in every database.  This can be a lot of OS I/O to get the `.frm` files.  The OS caches such.  I tested your query with my 1177 tables:

1st run: 32.54 seconds.
2nd run:  0.7 seconds.
3rd run:  0.7 seconds.

Try a second run on your "slower" machine.

Also, check this on both machines:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'table_open_cache';
```

It might be more than 5237 on the fast machine and less than 5237 on the slower machine.  (Actually, I don't think this is an issue.  I shrank my setting, but the `SELECT` continued to be about 0.7 sec.)